# Java error message "gc PS Mark Sweep in fire fighting mode"

Tags: java, tomcat, garbage-collection

When adding a zabbix jmx monitor for my Java application, I am getting a lot of error messages: `gc PS Mark Sweep in fire fighting mode`.

What does it mean and what is going to happen?

Answer (score 4):

According to [this](https://blog.svedr.in/posts/problem-gc-concurrent-mark-sweep-in-fire-fighting-mode.html) link it's Zabbix's way of telling that the [Concurrent Mark And Sweep](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gctuning/cms.html) (and probably any other) collector is performing "excessive" (in Zabbix's opinion) full stop GC's.

This *could* be an indication that the application doesn't have enough memory available for it, or just that the `CMS` GC algorithm isn't very suitable for the workload.